# I'm not getting the exact output i want using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, yaml, ruamel.yaml

I'm unable to get the desired output I need . Tried basic method like formatting string etc, but still didn't get the output I want.

```
from pathlib import Path

eth_file = Path("/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml")
yml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
data = yml.load(eth_file)


    eth = input("Enter interface name \n")
    addr = input("Enter IP address and mask. e.g., 8.8.8.8/8 \n")
    dns = input("Enter DNS \n")
    rts = input("Enter routes -to \n")
    rts1 = input("Enter routes via \n")

    new_ether = {eth: dict(
        addresses=[addr],
        nameservers=dict(addresses=f"[{dns}]"),
        routes=[dict(to=rts, via=rts1)]
    )}


    data['network']['ethernets'].update(new_ether)
    yml.dump(data, eth_file)
```

Output i got is like this:

```
      addresses:
      - ''
      nameservers:
        addresses: '[2.34]'
      routes:
      - to: ''
        via: ''
```

But i don't want *nameservers addresses* field in inverted commas like- **'[x.x]'**. I want this field in simple square brackets without any commas, for e.g.,- **[x.x]**.

```
        addresses: '[2.34]'

How I want it looks
nameservers:
        addresses: [2.34]         #without any inverted commas
```

Comment: Please create a [reprex] by removing all of the code that is not directly relevant to the question.

Comment: Do the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42143451/how-to-dump-list-from-python-to-yaml) help at all?

Comment: @quamrana Not yet

Comment: Does this answer your question? [YAML: Dump Python List Without Quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51757460/yaml-dump-python-list-without-quotes)

Comment: @GPhilo No because he is dumping the python list

Comment: @nonDucor what do u mean?

Comment: use eval('[2.34]'), it will give [2.34]. let me know if it worked

Comment: @RitwickJha no coz I'm storing the input in dns variable and passing it, using eval it count it as string and using formatted string the result isn't expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you load this YAML:

```
nameservers:
    addresses: [2.34]
```

you get a data structure with a dict like class at the root and as
value for the (only) root level key. The value for key `addresses`
is a list consisting of a single float (and it is in flow style).
If you have problems, you should always try to load the YAML that
you want to achieve and then analyse it and also dump it back to
YAML (to see if it changes).

Since `[` and `]` have special meaning in YAML, you certainly cannot
get the former at the beginning of a plain scalar string. If you
put that in as string, you will get the quote.

```py
# coding: utf-8
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

def flow_seq(*x):
    ret_val = ruamel.yaml.CommentedSeq(x)
    ret_val.fa.set_flow_style()
    return ret_val

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
data = dict(nameservers=dict(addresses=flow_seq(2.34)))
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
nameservers:
  addresses: [2.34]
```

Comment: It's working fine but when I trying to insert an IP address(8.8.8.8) it raises error of invalid syntax. It is working only with single dot digits adding two or more dot raises error

Comment: `2.34` is a (Python and YAML) float that can of course only have one dot. If you have an IP address you can only put that in Python source code as string (or as a special type. Any string consisting of numbers and **multiple** dots will be represented in YAML without quotes (as this cannot be misinterpreted as float). You have to process your input appropriately based on the number of dots in that input.

Comment: Single IP address(8.8.8.8) is working fine but when i add two IP addresses(for e.g., 8.8.8.8, 4.4.8.8) separated by a comma then it reads it as a string(e.g., ['8.8.8.8, 8.8.8.8']. What can I do so that it doesn't contain any inverted commas.

Comment: Convert the input to something that doesn't need quotes in YAML (hint: if there is a comma split the list and strip the items)